# How do i count str_split characters in each index to total index

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, count

I have the code which output result in index as example  `ABC` `DEF` `GHI` my problem is how do i count the characters in each index to total index example my expected result should be  3  and 9 
i have tried:

```
$text = "ABCDEFGHIK"; 
$num = str_split($text ,3); 
for($b = 0; $b<3; $b++)
{ 
  echo count($num);  
  echo count($num[$b]); 
}
```

my output result with the current code is 5 and 1 how do i acchieve this thanks in advance

Comment: strlen($num[$b])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `strlen` instead of `count` to find out string length

```
$text = "ABCDEFGHIK"; 
$num = str_split($text ,3); 
$cnt = 0;
$total = 0;
for($b = 0; $b<3; $b++){ 
$cnt = strlen($num[$b]); 
$total += $cnt;
}
echo $cnt;

echo $total;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/vdnou)